# Batch nested for loop failing syntax at IN

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, for-loop, nested-loops

I'm currently working on just a small batch script to run through `dumpsec` and pull out two lines of information that I need and discard all else. However, and I cannot figure out where I've gone wrong. At my first `FOR` nested in the first `IF`, I will receive a syntax error of

> IN not expected at this time

I've added and worked through all the options I can find on the man page for `FOR`, and gone through several dozen questions on this website as it's my goto 'what did I screw up this time'. My only thought is somehow the `IF` statement prior to the `FOR` loops is causing the issue?

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
CD "C:\Program Files (x86)\SystemTools\"
DUMPSEC /rpt=userscol /outfile=c:\report /saveas=csv /noheader
SET /A maxlines=23
SET /A linecount=1
SET /A size=1 
SET /A number=1
SET /A counter=10
:While
IF %size% LEQ 0 ( 

FOR /F %%i IN (C:\report) DO ( 
    PAUSE
    IF !linecount! GEQ %maxlines% GOTO ExitLoop
    ECHO %%i>>C:\PulledUser.txt
    SET /A linecount+=1
) 
:ExitLoop
FOR /F "skip=23 delims=*" IN (C:\report) DO (
    ECHO %%a>>c:\Holder.txt
)
XCOPY C:\Holder.txt C:\report /Y
DEL C:\Holder.txt /F /Q 

FOR /F %%i IN (C:\report) DO (
    SET size=%%~zi 
)

SET /P user=<C:\PulledUser.txt
SET /A uname%number%=%user%
SET /A number=%number%+1
SET /A linecount=0
XCOPY C:\PulledUser.txt C:\%user%.txt
DEL C:\PulledUser.txt /F /Q
GOTO While 
)
SET /A number=1
IF %counter% LEQ 10(
IF EXIST C:\%uname%%number%.txt (
    SET /A number=%number%+1
    SET /A counter=%counter%-1
    )
)
IF  %number% NEQ 0 (

FIND /N /I "%uname%%number%" C:\%uname%%number%.txt && FIND /N /I "pswdrequired" C:\%uname%%number%.txt >> C:\reports.txt 
DEL C:\%uname%%number%.txt
SET /A number=%number%-1
)

TYPE C:\reports.txt 
PAUSE
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing `%%a`in `FOR /F "skip=23 delims=*" IN (C:\report) DO (`

Comment: Thomas.W is correct about the missing %%A.  However, in addition, I'd recommend not nesting IFs, as this will break if you deal with a line containing brackets.  Do you have any more information regarding which two lines you require?  My reason for asking is that FINDSTR.EXE is quite often very useful for "pre-processing" a file prior to "FOR /F"'ing it.  Finally, I prefer handing off the line processing to a function - this prevents "(" or ")" breaking your FOR command.  If you give more info about the lines, I'll update the post with an example.

Comment: Thank you for your responses, I'll be trying Thomas' suggestion in a moment. 

Normally I would use findstr, but the output of dumpsec is to list all users and their associated group policy / local policy. The reason I'm doing the for loops to parse the file is to read out the first 23 lines, save to a user file with the user name, open the file again and delete the first 23 lines, rinse repeat until file size is 0. 

The lines out of dumpsec I need are the username (first), and 'pswdrequired' (line 12).

Comment: I think it could be done in a robust manner with with `findrepl.bat` but without sample data it's difficult to say.